# How can I change the bond type (single, double) of an existing bond in Avogadro?

Tags: bond, software

I have a molecule extracted from the PDB. When I load it into Avogadro, it has some misplaced bond types. I want to correct this, by setting the bond type (single, double) for these bonds. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this sample PDB file with annotations [here](https://www.umass.edu/microbio/rasmol/fumarate.pdb). It tells you how you can set single and double/triple/etc.  bonds in the file.

Comment: I'd suggest e-mailing the [Avogadro mailing lists](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Contact) with such questions. That's the best forum for Avogadro help. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the Avogadro website about the [draw tool](https://avogadro.cc/docs/getting-started/drawing-molecules/) you can change the bond order:

- By clicking on the bond - the bond order will go from single, to double, to triple, back to single.
- By setting the bond order and "drawing over" the bond. The new setting (e.g., double) will replace the existing bond.

Comment: That link is now dead, do you have an up-to-date link to it? Clicking on existing bond does nothing for me.